# Derivative and integration

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, derivatives

I have 2 questions here that I have doubts with.

> 1. If $y= \sin x $ , and $ y^{(n)}$ means "the $n$ derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ " then the smallest positive integer $n$ for which $y^{(n)} = y $  is ....

First I do the first derivative and 2nd and so on...

$y' = \cos x$

$y''= -\sin x $

does this mean $n= 2$ ?

Next question is:

> 2. If $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions , and if $f(x)\geq$, $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ , which of the following must be true?

[image]

Am I right to say I And II ?

Thanks !

Comment: one question per post please!

Comment: @user307640 If you found any of these answers to be helpful, you should accept one of them. :)

Answer (score 2):

In regards to question 1, $\sin x \ne - \sin x$, because this implies $1 = -1$, which is certainly not true. To find the answer keep differentiating,

\begin{align*}
y' &= \cos x \\
y'' &= -\sin x \\
y^{(3)} &= -\cos x \\
y^{(4)} &= \sin x
\end{align*}

So $n=4$

In regards to question 2, II is a basic property of integrals, where I and III are fairly easy to find counter examples for, try $f(x) = e^x$ and $g(x) = x^3 - \sqrt{x}$

Answer (score 2):

For question 1:
Your answer is wrong, because $-\sin x$ is not the same as $\sin x$, so $n$ has to be bigger than $2$.

Hints for question 2:
For I. and III. it is very easy to find counterexamples, just try some simple functions that come to your mind.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**: No, $n \ne 2$, because $\sin x \ne -\sin x$. If you differentiate two more times, you will get
$$y'''=-\cos x$$
and
$$y''''=\sin x$$
So, since the fourth derivative is equal to $\sin x$, which is the same as the starting function, $n=4$.

**Question 2:** II is definitely always true because it is a basic property of definite integrals. I and III can be disproven easily using a few examples. Both can be disproven by letting $f$ and $g$ be constant functions.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=2$ you get $-sin(x)$, which is different from $y=sin(x)$. Try $n=4$.

Second question, of the options you mention, option I is not in general true, for example $$\int_a^b x^2 \mathrm{d}x  = \int_a^b x*x \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{3}[b^3-a^3]$$ does not equal $$(\int_a^b x \mathrm{d}x) (\int_a^b x \mathrm{d}x) = \frac{1}{2}[b^2-a^2]*\frac{1}{2}[b^2-a^2]$$

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**

If $y = sinx$, then $y'''' = sinx$

If $y = cosx$, then $y'''' = cosx$